# File not adding in zip by bash script but work in command line in terminal

Tags: bash, grep, zip

I am running a script in cron and trying to add a file in a zip by below code,

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/mainfolder/cron

date=$(date --date=yesterday +%F)

FILE=/home/mainfolder/folder/$date.zip

if test -f "$FILE"; then

echo $date

else 

wget -r -np -nH --user=USER --password=PASSWORD https://sercret-website.com/$date.zip -P /home/mainfolder/folder/

zip -ur $date.zip file.txt

mkdir temp
cp /home/mainfolder/folder/$date.zip /home/mainfolder/temp/
cd /home/mainfolder/temp/

fi
```

my file name is yesterday date lets say today is 2019-12-18 (yyyy-mm-dd) my file name is 2019-12-17.zip

when I run in bash sh -x script.sh  it didn't work 
when i run normally in terminal it work well

```
zip -ur 2019-12-17.zip file.txt
```

I am using CentOS server.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong.

I tries

```
#!/bin/sh != #!/bin/bash
#!/bin/sh 
#!/bin/bash
```

nothing work

Comment: and what is current directory when your script runs? - you can add **pwd > /tmp/my-pwd** into your script and you will know the answer to your issue - use absolute file path for both file.txt and zip file.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny Let me add full script, it will help to understand better

Comment: @ MaximSagaydachny please refresh

Comment: should not you do zip -ur $FILE.zip instead of zip -ur $date.zip ? Your cwd is /home/mainfolder/cron and you are storing file to /home/mainfolder/folder so you are working with wrong ZIP /home/mainfolder/cron/$date.zip instead of $FILE. And you are creating temp in /home/mainfolder/cron but not in /home/mainfolder/

Comment: @CorOmnes : What does _normally_ in _when i run normally_ mean? And what does "it does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: just replace **cd /home/mainfolder/cron** with **cd /home/mainfolder/** and script context will be ok - i.e. you will be in proper folder for all commands of script to refer proper paths

Comment: @ MaximSagaydachny full path work fine, thanks...

Comment: @user1934428  Please read the question carefully

Answer (score 0):

I'd change `date=$(date --date=yesterday +%F)` to:

```
date=`date --date=yesterday +%F`
```

and write zip as

```
zip -ur ${date}.zip file.txt
```

and shebang as:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
```

Then I'd look for reason of failure in cron log files.